# What is the use of ; and .+ in GetMapping springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am currently working on a project where one @GetMapping is making
use of ;and +.
Given below is the controller class code.

```
 @RestController @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
 @RequestMapping("/v1") 
 public class RestServiceController {

 @GetMapping(path = "/{Id};{Time:.+}")   
 public ResponseEntity<Request> getSRequestById(@PathVariable String Id, @PathVariable String Time) {
 
  }
}
```

When I am Hitting the URL http://localhost:8080/v1/123. I am getting below warning
org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping for GET /v1/123

Comment: Can you also share your project file  structure ?

Answer (score 4):

The mapping contains a regular expression (RE) `.+`, that means at least one character. The `;` is a literal to separate the **id** from **time**.

Valid URL: /1108;11722222422, /AG8;TIME

Not valid URL: /123, /8;

Anyway, as long @PathVariable is mandatory (required=true by default) the RE is needless.